# Fetching multiple rows with specific IDs?

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch some specific rows from MySQL database using multiple ids, for example if I have to select only rows 201,567,991 etc...

like this

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * from tbl_name WHERE id = '201', '567', 'id-etc.'";
```

is it possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) should do the trick. Just put your list of numbers inside the brackets like so:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * from tbl_name WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3, ...)";
```

You don't need to quote numbers going into INT fields, however it's a very good idea to cast any variables to int, to minimise security vulnerability:

```
$var = (int)$var;
```

If you're using strings, however, *do* quote them as you normally would.

Comment: @ImranHussain, I would suggest just using `mysql_real_escape_string()` for everything and just quoting all your numbers. That way all your escaping code looks the same and you cannot make mistakes. If you leave an escaped string **unquoted** you are wide open to SQL-injection. If you quote a number everything works OK, with exactly the same performance.

Comment: This doesn't fetch rows in exactly the order given.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use `IN` [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * from tbl_name WHERE id IN ('201', '567')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use tge "IN" operator as in:|

```
 SELECT * from tbl_name WHERE id In ('201', '567', 'id-etc.')
```